# How to make iframe vertically responsive keeping aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a page with an youtube iframe. Here's what I need:
 - The video height will be a percentage of the browser window height.
 - If the user resizes the browser window moving the cursor up and down (making the window taller or shorter), the iframe height will keep the percentage, BUT ALSO THE VIDEO WILL PRESERVE IT'S ASPECT RATIO (the width will change along with the height)

**This needs to be totally responsive, not just on reload.**

The behavior is something like (in fantasy code):

```
iframe {
    height: 20%;         /* 20% of the browser window height  */
    width: height*1.64;  /* get the value in pixels and multiply by 1.64 */
}
```

The same way the photo behaves in this page:
http://hotdot.pro/en/#lophoto
(In fact I'm using the parallax javascript engine created by hotdot)

I've searched a lot for it on the web and found nothing.

Anybody knows how to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: Aspect ration of the iframe? you mean resize height AND WIDTH when the user resizes only the height of his window?

Comment: If you _know_ the aspect ratio then this can be done using a container element and absolute positioning of the iframe, making use of the fact that a vertical padding given in percentage refers to the width of the containing block.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code to FitVid.js? Maybe it wouldn't take much more than swapping height for width.

Comment: @CBroe And how would I set the width and height of the iframe? Do you have an example of that?

Comment: @LShetty Yes. I have edited the question, I think it's clearer now.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your help, but I ended up using javascript:

    window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
      var cw = $('.youtube').height();
      $('.youtube').css({
          'width': cw*1.64 + 'px',
          'margin-left': '-' + cw*0.82 + 'px'
      });
    });

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help guys, but I ended up using javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  var cw = $('.youtube').height();
  $('.youtube').css({
      'width': cw*1.64 + 'px',
      'margin-left': '-' + cw*0.82 + 'px'
  });
});
```

And I added the following inline css to the iframe element:

```
position: absolute;
top: 29%;
height: 37%;
```